# int32 storage in memory

Tags: c#, memory, bit, int32

I have a question about `int32 storage (c#)`.

32 bits means that the biggest number for int is 2^32.

`2^32 = 4294967296`,  if you divide it by 2 you get the maximum value for an int32 :

```
4294967296 / 2 = -2147483648 to 2147483648
```

So I thought half of the bits are for negative figures and the other for positive.
But that cant be true because `2^16 = 65536`.

Now my **question :**

How is this actually set up in memory?

Im really curious about your answers.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement

Comment: Pretty well formed question.. But presius is right. Basically since integers can hold negative values one of its bits in memory must be used to allow -1 and 1 to both exist (for example)

Comment: unsurprisingly, this has come up before.

Comment: You only need ONE bit for the sign, so there are 31 bits left for the representation of the actual number. The range is `-(2^31)` to `2^31-1`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Only one bit is used for sign (negative or positive)

> Int32 values are represented in 31 bits, with the thirty-second bit
>   used as a sign bit. Positive values are represented by using
>   sign-and-magnitude representation. Negative values are in two's
>   complement representation, [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.aspx)

```
Int32.MaxValue =  2^31 - 1 = 01111111111111111111111111111111                
Int32.MinValue = -2^31     = 10000000000000000000000000000000
```

I have found nice article to understand the two's complement [here](http://www.cs.cornell.edu/~tomf/notes/cps104/twoscomp.html).

**Conversion from Two's Complement**

Use the number `0xFFFFFFFF` as an example. In binary, that is:

```
1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111
```

What can we say about this number? It's first (leftmost) bit is 1, which means that this represents a number that is negative. That's just the way that things are in two's complement: a leading 1 means the number is negative, a leading 0 means the number is 0 or positive.

To see what this number is a negative of, we reverse the sign of this number. But how to do that? To reverse the sign you simply invert the bits (0 goes to 1, and 1 to 0) and add one to the resulting number.

The inversion of that binary number is, obviously:

```
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
```

Then we add one.

```
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0001
```

So the negative of `0xFFFFFFFF` is `0x00000001`, more commonly known as `1`. So `0xFFFFFFFF` is `-1`.

**Conversion to Two's Complement**

Note that this works both ways. If you have -30, and want to represent it in 2's complement, you take the binary representation of 30:

```
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0001 1110
```

Invert the digits.

```
1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1110 0001
```

And add one.

```
1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1110 0010
```

Converted back into hex, this is `0xFFFFFFE2`

**Edit, How does CPU performs subtraction using Two's complement**

The CPU performs the subtraction using addition on two's complement of negative number. Lets take an example of 8 bit numbers. We want to subtract 4 from seven.

```
7 = 00000111
4 = 00000100
```

Two' complement of 4

Step 1 take inverse of 00000100 by converting 0 to 1 and 1 to 0

```
00000100 -> 11111011
```

Step 2 Add one to inverse

```
11111011
00000001
========
11111100
```

**7- 4 = 7 + (Two's complement of 4)**

```
00000111 (binary representation of 7)
11111100 (binary representation after Two's complement of 4)
========
00000011  (binary representation of 3)
```

Comment: thanks for the good answer. but why is this so "complicated" ? since there is a sign bit why cant it be like that:                 value 2 = 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0010                                                                value -2= 1000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0010                                                                                                                                    i guess the reason why it cant be this way is the way the compiler calculates bit values, am i right?

Comment: Its explained very well here, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5793740/how-does-cpu-do-subtraction

Comment: Check my updated answer, I have added an example showing how CPU using Two's complement to perform subtraction using addition.