# adding an integer to a char array in c

Tags: c

It may be silly question but still am not getting it.
    I do have a char array say
     char arr[100] having some data

```
 char arry[100] ---- some data;
 int test;
 memcpy(&test,array+4,sizeof(int))
```

What does this memcpy will do
Thanks
SKP

Answer (score 5):

This might be useful in so-called serialization of data.

Say, if someone saved an integer into a file.

Then you read the file into a buffer (`arry` in your case) as a stream of bytes. Now you want to convert these bytes into real data, e.g. in your case integer `test` which has been stored with offset 4.

There are several ways to do that. One is to use [memcpy](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/memcpy) to copy bytes into area where compiler would treat them as an integer.

So to answer your question:

```
 memcpy(&test,array+4,sizeof(int))
```

...will copy sizeof(int) number of bytes, starting from 4-rth byte from `array` into memory allocated for variable `test` (which has type `int`). Now `test` has the integer value which was saved into `arry` originally, probably using the following code:

```
 memcpy(array+4, &original_int, sizeof(int))
```

Doing this requires some knowledge of hardware and the language. As there are many complications, among which:

- [byte order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) in integers.;
- [data alignment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment);

Answer (score 2):

It just copy the element `array[4]` to variable `test`. On 32-bit machine `sizeof(int)` = `4`. `memcpy` will copy `4` bytes to the address `&test` which can hold `4` bytes.

Comment: Removed after your edit. The first sentence by itself is wrong, since it implied only one byte is copied when in fact elements 4-7 are copied as you later clarify.

Answer (score 2):

This will copy probably 4 bytes (depending on your machine and compiler--your `int` might be bigger or smaller) from the 4th through 7th bytes of `arry` into the integer `test`.

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation of [`memcpy()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/memcpy/) :

> ```
> void * memcpy ( void * destination, const void * source, size_t num );
> ```
>
> Copies the values of `num` bytes from the location pointed by `source` directly to the memory block pointed by `destination`.

In your case :

- `num`=`sizeof(int)`
- `destination`=`&test` A pointer to test
- `source`=`&array[4]` A pointer to the fourth element of the array of char `array`

Hence, if `sizeof(int)==4` it will copy `array[4]`, `array[5]`,`array[6]` and `array[7]` to `test`

There are questions that can help you understand the memory layout of integers :

- [int32 storage in memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22760105/int32-storage-in-memory)
- [How is an integer stored in memory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18518018/how-is-an-integer-stored-in-memory)

There is also an issue with endianless : on my computer, `array[4]` corresponds to the least significant byte.

Consequently, if `array[7]=0x80` and `array4]=array[5]=array[6]=0x00` then `test` will contain 00000080 and `test` will worth -2^31.

if `array[7]=0x2A` and `array[5]=array[6]=array[4]=0x00` then `test` will contain 2A000000 and `test` will worth 42 (that is 0x0000002A).

Here is a test code to be compiled by `gcc main.c -o main`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main(int  argc,char *argv[]){

    char array[100];
    int test;
    printf("sizeof(int) is %ld\n",sizeof(int));

    array[4]=0x00;
    array[5]=0;
    array[6]=0;
    array[7]=0x80;
    memcpy(&test,&array[4],sizeof(int));
    printf("test worth %d or(hexa) %x\n",test,test);

    array[4]=0x2A;
    array[5]=0;
    array[6]=0;
    array[7]=0x00;
    memcpy(&test,&array[4],sizeof(int));
    printf("test worth %d or(hexa) %x\n",test,test);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Generally the C library function **void *memcpy(void *str1,const void *str2,size_t n)** copies **n** characters from memory area **str2** to memory area **str1**, where:

**str1** – this is pointer to the destination array where the content is to be copied, type-casted to a pointer of type void*

**str2** -- this is pointer to source of data to be copied, type-casted to a pointer of type void*

**n** -- this is the number of bytes to be copied

memcpy returns a pointer to destination, which is str1

In your case, is copied the contents of the array, from the address pointed to by array[4] up to sizeof (int) bytes (4 bytes in this case, if you have a 32bit machine), the address pointed to by test