# The SUB instruction in CPU

Tags: assembly, cpu, cpu-architecture, cpu-registers, alu

Consider the 8-bit CPU only. Let’s say we have two registers, R1 and R2, when performing `SUB R1, R2`, R2 will be first converted to its two’s complement and than add with R1, but I’m wondering, what if R1 is holding 47 and R2 is holding 250? Cause obviously 250 is out of the range of the signed number in 8-bit, so it can’t be converted to its two’s complement, then how does CPU handle this situation?

Comment: That "trick" for implementing a binary subtractor by preprocessing the input to a binary adder (i.e. making a binary adder-subtractor) works whether you interpret the bits as unsigned or as signed-negative.  Note that an ALU wouldn't really do `0 - 250` or `~250 + 1` to get the inverse, it would just bitwise NOT and do the +1 by feeding in a carry-in of `1` into the low bit.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adder%E2%80%93subtractor .  That's also necessary for the FLAGS result to correspond to the original subtraction for all cases.

Comment: [Aarch64 SUB etc instructions defined as add with carry operation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77672643) / [How does the CPU do subtraction?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5793740)

Comment: The CPU doesn't care if the number is signed or unsigned — it just performs a mechanical operation.

Comment: "*then how does CPU handle this situation*" — it is not the CPU that needs to handle this, it is the program, and hence the programmer.

Comment: It is up to the programmer to write a program that makes sense, including guarding against overflow when overflow is possible, since overflow usually means the simple answer doesn't make sense. Guarding against overflow means either detecting when the program cannot do the operation and taking an alternate course of action, or using an increased precision (e.g. 16 bit, and yes, even 8 bit computers can do 16 bit arithmetic).

Comment: I forgot to say this in my earlier comment; I think \@500 programmer dude alluded to it: If you're considering a signed interpretation of the bits, you can't have `250` in the first place.  You actually have `-6`.  Addition and subtraction (and non-widening multiplication) are the same operation for unsigned and for 2's complement so as Erik says, you just feed the data into the ALU and get a result, and choose to look at the signed Overflow flag or the unsigned Carry flag as appropriate.

Comment: Most processors (and programming languages) settle on integer arithmetic that consumes two unsigned inputs and produces unsigned output or consumes two signed inputs and produces signed output.  If you need to either consume one unsigned and one signed or to look at the output result differently, then a conversion is required and these conversions themselves can also overflow, so again programs need to handle that.